# Have trouble understanding vector projections

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

I'm currently reading about vector projections and have trouble understanding them. For example, the formula for finding the distance between a dot and a line is $d=\frac{
​∣a(x_0​)+b(y_0​)+c∣}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}​$, while the formula for finding the projection of a vector onto another one is $\frac{b ⋅ a}{b ⋅ b} ⋅ a$. I read a vector proof of the 1st formula, which seemed logical to me as we were projecting one vector onto another one, but somewhy it differed from the latter.

Could anybody tell me why is it so and from where the 2nd formula comes from? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Note that the vector projection formula is not $*$, but rather $\cdot$, the dot product.

Comment: @EvanWeissburg Yes, of course I meant that. Corrected

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1146784/representation-of-dot-product-of-a-vector

Comment: @EvanWeissburg Unfortunately, that doesn't answer my question. I don't understand, for example, why we calculate the norm of the vector in the 1st formula, but only dot product in the 2nd one. The same goes for the nominator. Why there are so many differences? And what does not only a.b mean, but the whole fraction (b.a/b.b).a.

Comment: These are formulas for different things. The first is the distance from a point to a line. The second is the projection of a vector onto another. There's no reason they should have the *same* formula. These formulas are related because you can use one to prove the other, but that requires transforming a problem about distance from a point to a line to a problem about vector projection (or vice versa). This ends up changing around the parameters, so the final formula ends up looking different. However, if you look through the proof, you'll see that the projection formulas are the same.

Comment: The vector projection is $[(a\cdot b)/(b\cdot b)]b$. I think there's a typo.

Comment: @Othin Yes, thanks for correcting me

Comment: @memerson I didn't manage to find any proof which showed the steps of the transformation, only "it is obvious that". I'd be grateful for any links

Comment: @Bob Wikipedia has a proof using projection at this link. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line?oldformat=true#A_vector_projection_proof. The only thing to make sure you know is that if $v$ is a vector $v\cdot v = |v|^2$. This means that if you you have $a$ and $b$, the projection is $b\cdot a/|a|^2 a$ and so if we take the magnitude of that we just get $b\cdot a/|a|$.

Comment: @memerson Yes, I've seen it and the problem is that I don't understand how |QP.n| / ||n|| has been constructed.

Comment: @memerson Thanks, saw the edit.

Comment: That's fair. As far as $QP$ is concerned we construct it by simply picking any point $Q$ on the line and finding the vector from $P$ to $Q$. Constructing $n$ is more difficult. In 2D, you can use that there is only 1 line perpendicular to the given line which goes through $Q$, and so the wikipedia proof finds the slope of this line and uses it for $n$. In $\mathbb{R}^3$ finding $n$ is more difficult and definitely not completely clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that the direction of a vector $b$ is given by $\hat{b}=\frac{b}{||b||}$. You can decompose $\hat{b}$ into a component that is parallel to $a$ and one that is orthogonal to it. Since the cosine of 90º is zero, this operation will "select" the component that is parallel to $a$. This gives you a number, which represents (plus or minus) the length of the orthogonal projection of $\hat{b}$ onto $a$. This is called the *scalar* projection. The *vector* projection is obtained by multiplying the vector$\hat{b}=\frac{b}{||b||}$ by the scalar projection. This results in $$(\hat{b}\cdot a)\hat{b}= \frac{b\cdot a}{\sqrt{b\cdot b}}\hat{b}= \frac{b\cdot a}{b\cdot b}b.$$

Note that this is a vector, so it shouldn't equal any distance at all. If you take a vector that is perpendicular to a line, represent it in a way that it starts at a point $a$ in that line and ends at a point $b$ above it, *then* you can use the absolute value of the scalar projection to prove this distance formula you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks! That cleared a lot of things to me. And what's the difference between scalar and vector projections?

Comment: Scalar projection is a number which represents length of the orthogonal projection of these vectors, with a minus sign in the case the case this projection has an opposite direction from $a$ and a plus sign if it is the same direction.  The vector projection is a vector that is obtained by the prescription given above.